# Dynamics CRM Duplicate Detection Enforced

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can duplicate detection rules be enforced for new records?
Currently the user is notified of a possible duplicate, but can choose to ignore the warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The duplicate detection rules in CRM 2011 don't actually prevent the creation of duplicate records, they just detect what looks like a duplicate and show a warning to the user (just as you're experiencing)

If you actually want to enforce that duplicates are not created, you'll need to create your own plugin, and register it for the Create message of the entity that you want to prevent duplicate detection.  Once the plugin fires, it does a quick query to see if the current entity being created already exists.

The kicker is, that even with a plugin that functions perfectly, due to multiple servers / threads, it will still be possible to create a duplicate, but this would require two separate users performing the creates nearly simultaneously and depending on your load, may never occur.

Comment: +1 for a depth of gotcha. If dealing with malicious users, I'd register the plugin as async and let it even delay a random number of time units. Still, it **will** be possible to create dupes but it'll be darn hard.